# how to add two vm hosts to foreman puppet master

Tags: ubuntu, puppet, puppetlabs-apache, theforeman

I recently installed foreman puppet in ubuntu 14.04 LTS which I am running in virtual box. I have configured its FQDN as `127.0.1.1 ubuntu.localhost.com ubuntu`.

I successfully installed the foreman puppet in it.
so we run puppet master here and for puppet agent, we run it once using the command `puppet agent --test`,
so basically the puppet agent is on the same machine as the puppet master.
The puppet master is connected locally to foreman and
foreman is running locally at https://ubuntu.localhost.com.

I am running windows7 basically and I installed virtual box in it and then I am accessing ubuntu.
So, now I want to add a new host to my puppet master and I want to also access it through foreman.

For that I created new virtual machine with ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
How can I add this new VM to my puppet master and make it act as a puppet agent? I have set this new VM's FQDN as `127.0.1.2 ubuntuLight.localhost.com ubuntuLight`.

Answer (score 0):

The steps to add new machines in foreman:

- first run of "puppet agent -t" will generate certificates. If you don't have autosign in foreman set, you will have to go to your puppet master and sign the certificates. Else, the run have the same result as next step
- second run of "puppet agent -t" will actually execute a run puppet, but it will probablt do nothing, since you don't have any roles assigned to the node. After this run, the new machines should appear in foreman
- login in foreman and add a role/classes to the new machine and do any other configuration you need (set Location, Organization, etc.)
- new "puppet agent -t" that will actually apply a catalog with the above role or classes

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-puppet-to-manage-your-server-infrastructure#install-puppet-agent --in this link they have told how to add or install new host to foreman puppet. if i follow this tutorial, will i be able to add my new VM to my foreman puppet? And IP address assignmet is correct?

Comment: can you please reply to my comment